# What is the first event where we can fetch Cache data in WCF application?

Tags: wcf, caching, iis

I've winform application where I exposed a WCF service and it is hosted on IIS on the server, and there are around 10 methods in it.

There is some common data that I need in computation of all 10 methods. What I want is to get this common data only once when service start and put it in cache so that all the methods can get the data from this cache instead of getting it from database.

One thing I can do is to check whether there is cache available, is not then fetch it otherwise use existing. But I've to do it in all the exposed methods because I don't know which methods will be called first. So need a clean and short way to do this.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What are you currently using for caching? Anything at all?

Comment: We are having some static classes, we push data to their static variables so that we can read them later. This is what our caching is.

Comment: The most simple way then could be to add initialization methods to those static classes and run them when the service starts. I use MemoryCache, rather than static classes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx). It's good for light weight stuff, which it sounds like you might have here. It's built in to .Net, and it is easy to work with.

Comment: Irrespective of cache mechanism I'm looking for event where I can fill cache. But as per your suggestion, If I put my Cache fetch code in constructor of this static class so that as soon as any of the cache item is initialized this will be called and static constructor can be called only once so hopefully this will resolve my problem. What do you think Richards?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. It should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks Richards, I'll try this approach. If it doesn't work will come back to this comment section again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple solution of my this problem. In Cache class I've add a static constructor and there I wrote the code of fetching cache data. As we all know static constructor can be called only once and it can't be called explicitly. So as soon as we try to read any variable of Cache class (all are static variable to hold cache data), our static constructor will be called automatically and it'll fill cache data to respective static variables.